# Select row if column value not same as previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table like below

```
No. FName Age  Tag
1    abc   22    c
2    xyz   60    c
3    pqr   62    i
4    abc   22    i
5    abc   32    i
```

I want the result to be returned as

```
No. FName Age  Tag
1    abc   22    c
2    xyz   60    c
3    pqr   62    i
5    abc   32    i
```

Requirement is that if a column `Name` **AND** column `Age` value is same for rows with `tag=c and tag=i` , than the `tag=i` row should **not** be selected .
 Row no. 1 and Row no. 4 have same values `(Name,age)=(abc,22)` but row 4 has tag = i.
So row no 4 above `(abc,22,i)` has to be left out. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  No, FName, Age, Tag,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, Age
                                ORDER BY Tag ASC) rn
    FROM    tableName
    WHERE   TAG IN ('c','i')
)
SELECT  No, FName, Age, Tag
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5a7b/2)

if you have other special values on `TAG`,

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  No, FName, Age, Tag,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, Age
                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN TAG = 'c' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC) rn
    FROM    tableName
    WHERE   TAG IN ('c','i')
)
SELECT  No, FName, Age, Tag
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER   BY No
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5a7b/3)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT Fname, Age, MIN(tag) Tag
FROM   TableName
WHERE  TAG IN ('c','i')
GROUP  BY Fname, Age
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5a7b/12)

Comment: can't i do this in a select query in where condition using CASE ?

Comment: I meant can this be done without CTE , using a single select query in which i can specify condition in where clause ? Where I intend to use is complex query..

Answer (score 4):

I think you can simply ignore all the rows with `tag` = 'i' if already exists row with same `age`, `name` and `tag` = 'c' :

```
select * from TableName t1
where not exists 
          (select 1 
           from TableName 
           where FNAme = t1.FNAme and Age = t1.Age and t1.Tag = 'i' and tag = 'c')
```